# hibernate deleting child from attached parent

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I`ve got a parent like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue()
@Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
private int id;

@OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity=Priority.class, orphanRemoval=true)
@IndexColumn(name="idx")
@JoinColumn(name="employee_id")
private List<Priority> priorities;
```

And a child class like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="priority")
public class Priority implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
private int id;

@Column(length=255)
private String focus;

@ManyToOne(optional=true)
@JoinColumn(name="employee_id", nullable=false)
private Employee employee;
```

I´m just operating with the parent. I want to read, add, edit and remove priorities from the parent. I dont´t want to update each change for itself. I want to update all changes at once.
What I do:
Reading an employee and listing his priorities. now i add a priority, change one entry.
Now saving with

```
utx.begin();
emp = em.merge(employee);
utx.commit();
```

Adding, editing and reading works fine, but when removing and saving i get an exception.

```
08:57:02,159 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Hibernate: update priority set employee_id=null, idx=null where employee_id=? and id=?
08:57:02,161 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
08:57:02,162 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Column 'employee_id' cannot be null
08:57:02,164 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) ARJUNA012125: TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion - failed for SynchronizationImple< 0:ffff7f000101:3dfa0b66:52a577bb:11, org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization@438f8fc4 >: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Column 'employee_id' cannot be null
```

This exception doesn`t make sens for me. I think it is, that hibernate doesent delete the orphant corectly whene I remove the child from the parent, while it is attached.

```
priority.setEmployee(null);
employee.getPriorities().remove(priority);
```

I tried different ways to do so but I get either an exception or it don`t delete it from database.

(By the way I`m using MySQL for database)

Comment: confused with your question,Can you please add some code of removing and saving priority from employee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are getting correct error from hibernate

when you annotate `Employee employee` as

```
@JoinColumn(name="employee_id", nullable=false)
```

this means that the employee field of an Priority class should not be null .

priority.setEmployee(null);

on this line you are setting employee to null and trying to violate the ***NOT NULL*** constraint you applied on employee field of a Priority class

```
08:57:02,162 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Column 'employee_id' cannot be null
```

also you have mentioned `cascade={CascadeType.ALL}` it means any operation performed on parent should be performed on child so when you delete Parent class then all related child entries of this parent also get deleted so set it according to your needs

Answer (score 0):

what you propably want is`inverse="true" cascade="all;delete-orphan"`